# Create a bar graph by displaying a row of asterisks, that will read an input file of data

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, while-loop

Write a C++ program that will read an input file of data of today's sales rounded to the nearest $1000 for each of three stores.  A sample input file can be found in the module.  The name of the file - sales.txt - should be located in the current directory of your project.  The program should then produce a bar graph displaying each store's sales.  Create each bar in the graph by displaying a row of asterisks.  Each asterisk should represent $1000 of sales.

the download.txt file reads:

10000

8000

5000

What I want the file to look like is:

```
Today's Sales Chart

Gathering input from file...

Daily Sales (each * = $1000)

Store 1:   *********

Store 2:   ******

Store 3:   *******
```

I tried a while loop but I don't know how to include the .txt or bar graph

```
#include <iostream>;
#include <fstream>;
#include <string>;

using namespace std;

int main()
{
//Variables
    int store1;
    int store2;
    int store3;

// Display table heading
    cout << "Today's sales Chart\n" << endl;
    cout << "Gathering input from file...\n";
    cout << "\nDaily Sales (each * = $1000)\n";

    ifstream inputfile;
    inputfile.open("download.txt");



    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are trying to input from source.txt and output to download.txt, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question once.
You should be able to do:

`string line;` Create a variable that you'll store line in.

`while(inputfile >> line){` Loop through each line in the file.

`int x = stoi(line)` Convert the line (string) to an integer.

In the while loop you can do what you need to do with `x`, i.e. find out how many asterisks you need. So:

```
ifstream inputfile;
inputfile.open("download.txt")
string line;
while(inputfile >> line){
    int x = stoi(line); //will be 10000 in first loop
    int i = x / 1000; //number of asterisks
    for(int j = 0;j < i;j++){
        cout << "*";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Hope it helps.

EDIT: Obviously you can assign to your store variables and use them instead if required.